# Add image to iText dynamically on PDF file

Tags: itext

Can some one please help me what is missing in my code, I am trying to add image in to PDF generation

```
    fillFieldValue(stamper.getAcroFields(),agntCertBean);
    Image image1 = Image.getInstance(bb);
    image1.scaleAbsolute(25f, 25f);
    PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();       
    AcroFields.FieldPosition fldPos = (AcroFields.FieldPosition)     
    form.getFieldPositions("ProfilePciture");
    overContent.addImage(image1);
    stamper.close();                                 
    reader.close();
```

Comment: The question speaks of "PDF generation"; the code is about "PDF manipylation".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code without paying too much attending, I see two major mistakes:

[1.] There's something wrong with this line:

```
AcroFields.FieldPosition fldPos = (AcroFields.FieldPosition)form.getFieldPositions("ProfilePciture");
```

The `getFieldPositions()` method returns a `List` of `FieldPosition` elements and you're casting that list to a `FieldPosition` object. That won't work, you need something like this:

```
AcroFields.FieldPosition fldPos = form.getFieldPositions("ProfilePicture").get(0);
```

[2.] You get the position of the picture field, but you're not doing anything with it! You're not setting the position of the image!

Remove these two lines:

```
image1.scaleAbsolute(25f, 25f);
PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
```

Add these lines after you've obtained the field position:

```
Rectangle rect = fldPos.position;
image1.scaleToFit(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
image1.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(fldPos.page);
```

In these lines you scale the image so that it fits the field and you set the coordinates of the image. You also get the `PdfContentByte` instance for the correct page instead of from the first page.

You may have other errors, but please fix these first!